# Tkinter Embedded Matplotlib display issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, python-3.4

I'm working on curve fitting using the Radial Basis Neural Network. I have succeeded in embedding my plot to the tkinter canvas after following [this guide](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk2.html).
My problem however is that when I run my code, the plot does not display in the canvas unless I either expand or contract the GUI window. I have searched for related problems here but I couldn't find one addressing specifically this issue. I am using python 3.4.2.

```
from tkinter import *
import math
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
import scipy
import scipy.linalg
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class RadialBasisNetwork:

    def  __init__(self):

        window = Tk()
        window.title("RBF Curve Fitting")
        self.f = Figure(figsize=(4,3), dpi=100)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f, master=window)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        frame0 = Frame(window)
        frame0.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        title = Label(frame0, text = "RBF Network Controller", font = "Times 12 bold")
        title.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    def Plot(self):

        x = np.linspace(x_0, x_1, num = steps) # generate domain of x
        plot_title = "model of " + model    
        a = self.f.add_subplot(111)
        a.plot(x,ypred, 'r--') # plot x against predicted y
        a.plot(x,y)            # plot x against actual y (target)
        a.legend(["Fit", "Target"], loc = "best", frameon = False, labelspacing = 0)
        a.set_title(plot_title) 
        a.set_ylabel('Y axis')
        a.set_xlabel('X axis')

RadialBasisNetwork()
```

Comment: Could you write a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It would help to have something we can copy/paste and run and directly see your problem. With the code you posted I can't seem to reproduce the problem (on Python 2.7).